# Why is the variable in the python call to Watson Language Translator not resolved

Tags: ibm-watson, language-translation

In python, I want to send a variable string to Watson Language Translator v3, using the code below. However the return code is 400, indicating a required parameter is missing. When instead of the variable **j** I use a literal string (so: **data = '{"text":"hello there"},{"model_id":"en-es"}'** I get the correct translation returned. How should I use the variable to get a translation returned instead of code 400?

```
import requests, json

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
params = (('version', '2018-05-01'),('X-Watson-Learning-Opt-Out', 'true')):

j=json.dumps("hello there")
print(j)

data = '{"text":j},{"model_id":"en-es"}'

r = requests.post(
        'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/translate', 
        headers=headers, params=params, data=data, auth=('xxx', 'xxx'))

print(r)
y=json.loads(r.text)
s= y['translations'][0]['translation']
print(s)
```

Comment: The problem is `{"text":j}` - this won't substitute the contents of `j` into the expression here, nor will the value of j be passed to the remote server so it knows what you meant by it. You either want [one of the string substitution mechanisms](https://pyformat.info/#simple), or you want to assemble your JSON payload as an object (where you could address `j` directly) and then serialise that into JSON, which would pick up your `j` value then. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Thanks for your response and explanation, I would prefer the shortest coding solution, I guess that is string substitution? How would you code that exactly ?

Comment: Following your hint, the following code does the job:

`  k="hello everybody"

data={"text":"{0}".format(k),"model_id": "en-es"}

j=json.dumps(data)

r = requests.post('https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/translate', 
                  headers=headers, params=params, data=j, 
                      auth=('xxx', 'xxx'))
`

Thanks for your help